# Error:(31, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'targetSdkVersion()'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:android-ColorPickerPreference')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile files('lib/dashclock-api-r2.0.jar')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19.1
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Fri Aug 28 03:51:32 IRDT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Error:(31, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'targetSdkVersion()'
Possible causes:

The project 'DroidPersianCalendar-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ask a question here and not just post and error. Also, add a [mcve] of the code that generated this error.

Comment: `targetSdkVersion` requires API Version not the SDK Build Tools verison. So it should be `19`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a bad `targetSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` script.

Change

```
targetSdkVersion 19.1
```

into

```
targetSdkVersion 19
```

Also you should change (it is not the reason of your issue)

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

into

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Your script should be somenthing like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"  // or 22.0.1 , 23.0.0

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:android-ColorPickerPreference')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile files('lib/dashclock-api-r2.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: But
The problem is that when i change targetSdkVersion to 19 was screened this error :

Comment: Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project ':PersianCalendar'. Minimum required is 19.1.0

Comment: I do not have in android stodio 0.5 this error and the project was working properly.

Comment: Don't confuse buildToolsVersion with targetSdkVersion. Use buildToolsVersion "19.1.0" or I suggest using buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" or buildToolsVersion "23.0.0" but check if you have updated your SDK Manager.

Comment: @mahdizz Updated the answer